# How to return a line from an array by searching for a specific value in said line

Tags: javascript

good evening, I am trying to use a single value to search an array, and return the full line the said value is in.

The Array is set up like this in string form:
Xanax,Brand,Anxiety,Code

However, now I'm stuck with calling back only the Medication, and not the full line the Medication is in, sadly.  I would like to be able to grab each variable in a line, and make them their own independent variables outside of the array so I can use them for something else.

```
this.importDataObject("MEDDIAGNOSISICD-10.txt", "C:/Users/dell/Documents/tab 
excel/MEDDIAGNOSISICD-10.txt");
var oFile = this.getDataObjectContents("MEDDIAGNOSISICD-10.txt");
var cFile = util.stringFromStream(oFile, "utf-8");
var fileArray = cFile.split('\t');
var Med = this.getField("Medications 1");

var Index = fileArray.indexOf(Med.value);
var Call = fileArray[Index];
console.println(Call);
```

Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: Can you show us the structure/contents of `fileArray`? Can just be dummy data.

Comment: I think he did that already: "The Array is set up like this in string form: Xanax,Brand,Anxiety,Code"

Comment: @FabianKüng     The fileArray is structured like this:                             
Medication, Brand, Anxiety, Code         With the "Code" sometimes missing from the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are running the `indexOf` method on the whole array, you need to run it on the each value instead. Try a `for` loop before you check `IndexOf` method.

Like this:

```
var i, Index;
for (i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) { 
  Index = fileArray[i].indexOf(Med.value);
  if(Index > -1) console.log('Your search is found in ' + fileArray[i] );
}
```

Note that, in here the variable `Index` will be `0` or larger if that search is successful. And will be of value `-1` if no match is found.

Comment: I think this is the correct solution, however note that it's better to name variables camelCase because the editor will mark it as a class instead. Also note that console.printLn() is not a function and u should use console.log()

Comment: Sorry for the bad clarification, I am writing this code in Adobe Acrobat, which uses some separate functions where others do not work.